# Constrain y-axis on R dendrogram plot

Tags: r, axis, dendrogram

I'd like to constrain the y-axis on dendrogram plot in R. Now, I have the y-axis ranging from 1 to 3000. Is the correct function to achieve this `ylim`? How should I do it?

```
plot(fit, main = 'Dendrogram', xlab = '', 
ylim =c(1,500), sub ='', axes = TRUE, ylab = 'Distance')
```

Comment: You're using `plot()` to construct the dendrogram, I assume from the result of `hclust()` or something similar? Did including the `ylim=` argument not solve the issue?

Comment: Do you mean changing the heights of the dendrogram itself, or to trim the plot in the Y axis?

Comment: p.s: please take a tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

A `ggplot` solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)
ggdendrogram(fit) + ylim(1,500)
```